# Custom Css for scroll bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i am looking for the customized scroll bar css. pls have a look into the attached image and the code sample below
I need the three lines on scroll bar thumb as shown in the below image.
do we have to add image on thumb or is it possible to use any kind of gradient styles? Any help is appreciated.

[image: Click here for the sample image what i am looking for]

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #6c7a85;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
  background-color: #64b6fd;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 300px;overflow: auto;width: 20%;;">
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
<p> Testing data </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set he background image inside `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: url('https://www.pngjoy.com/pngl/41/952512_hamburger-icon-menubuttom-hamburger-menu-icon-white-transparent.png') #64b6fd;
 background-size:8px 16px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
}
```

**Updated snippet :**

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 background-color: #6c7a85;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: url('https://www.pngjoy.com/pngl/41/952512_hamburger-icon-menubuttom-hamburger-menu-icon-white-transparent.png') #64b6fd;
 background-size:8px 16px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div style="height: 300px;overflow: auto;width: 20%;;">
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
  <p> Testing data </p>
</div>
</body>
```